# Не всплывает клавиатура в приложении

Tags: android, delphi

Поставил Delphi XE5, там есть разработка под Android и iOS. Но не всплывает клавиатура в приложении - по сути, невозможно ничего ввести.

Быть может, где-то что-то нужно дописать? Клавиатура нужна в `WebBrowser`.

```
var   Keyboard:
IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
Keyboard.ShowVirtualKeyboard(webbrowser1);
```

Клавиатура вызывается, но ничего не вводится.

Comment: Рекомендую отказаться от разработке пол Android на XE 5 Delphi,

Comment: Спасибо конечно. Но разве нет другого выхода?

Comment: Есть! Java :)

Comment: ахахха)) Ну и эклипс

Comment: Ну насчет того, что не стоит пытаться писать под Андрюшу на другом языке, кроме Java можно привести довольно много аргументов:

    1. Андроид использует виртуальную машину Java
    2. На другом языке вы будете постонно заставлять себя костылями, пытаясь обойти языковые различия
    3. Почти вся литература и документация по программингу под Андрюшу предпологает использование Java
    4. Вопрос производительности тоже никуда не делся
    5. ......
    6. ??????

Comment: Пример из моей жизни: лет так 10-12 назад я пытался писать код OpenGL и DirectX (школьное увлечение), используя Borland Delphi. После месяца мучений и постоянного серфинга по инету в поисках документации, я в итоге решил (с помощью дельных советов на различных форумах), что хватит заниматься ерундой и начал изучать C++. Теперь вспоминаю Паскаль как страшный сон и зря потраченное время.

Comment: @MDJHD Если спрашивают о том, как чинить УАЗик, а ему говорят - "Купи Японскую машину и будет всё хорошо", Является ли это хорошим ответом? И решает ли владельца УАЗика - его проблем? Я знаю, что JAVA лучше и не собираюсь это оспаривать, но задача именно на Delphi

Comment: В веббраузере да и любых других компонентах клавиатуру не нужно показывать принудительно. Сам `TWebBrowser` является всего лишь враппером над нативным компонентом целевой платформы. Будет поле ввода, которое предусматривает показ клавиатуры - веббраузер сам ее вызовет при получении этим полем фокуса. Возможно, на отображаемой страничке нет форм, которые нужно заполнять?